# Client disconnected while using HttpRequest uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a website,using .net 4.5.I use the following code to upload files

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadTempAttach()
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = null;
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile postFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
                file = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(postFile) as HttpPostedFileBase;
                var result = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=> FileUploadHelper.SaveTempFile(file));
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
               
            }
        }
```

recently,I usually received the err messge,I asked serveral user,they claimed that they  closed their browser when the file is still uploading(they found the process bar is not going on):

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): 与远程主机通信时发生错误。错误代码是 0x800703E3。 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): 由于线程退出或应用程序请求，已中止 I/O 操作。 (异常来自 HRESULT:0x800703E3)
   在 System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   在 System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   在 System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   在 System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()
   在 System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   在 System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm()
   在 System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   在 System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProvider..ctor(ControllerContext controllerContext, IUnvalidatedRequestValues unvalidatedValues)
   在 System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   在 System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   在 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   在 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   在 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   在 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

what can i do to fix this problem ? how to avoid this error ,I do not catch the errorr

Comment: _"what can i do to fix this problem ?"_ - What problem? It works as designed. You can chose to ignore the error, but that's about it.

Comment: i want to catch this error or avoid it，is there any code i can add to catch or avoid?

Comment: Your code looks like you already ignore all exceptions thrown by the upload process? You cannot "avoid" the exception happening, because it is the user who closes the connection unexpectedly, that causes it. So all you can do is catch and maybe do some cleanup or ignore completely.